# how to put threejs building on mapbox to its real place

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl-js

currently i've load eiffel tower obj file, and render it using threejs, but how can i put the building on map to its place in real world. i use mapgox-gl-js to handle map issues, for its convenience on 3d map.
[image: result]

```
style: {
    "version": 8,
    "sources": {
      "satellite": {
        "type": "raster",
        "url": "mapbox://mapbox.satellite",
        "tileSize": 256
      },
      "canvas": {
        type: 'canvas',
        canvas: 'idOfMyHTMLCanvas',
        // animate: true,
        coordinates: [
          [-74.02204952394804, 40.706782422418456],
          [-73.99115047610259, 40.706782422418456],
          [-73.99115047610259, 40.72021689994298],
          [-74.02204952394804, 40.72021689994298]
        ],
        contextType: 'webgl'
      }
    },
    "layers": [{
      "id": "satellite",
      "type": "raster",
      "source": "satellite"
    }, {
      "id": "video",
      "type": "raster",
      "source": "canvas"
    }]
}
```

thank you for any help.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to check out [Threebox](https://github.com/peterqliu/threebox), which is designed to sync a Three.js scene graph with a Mapbox GL JS map.

Answer (score 5):

This question is quite old, but indeed as suggested by @lauren-budorick, it took me 5 minutes to do this sample using the latest version of [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) and the result is like this [image: Eiffel Tower]

[image: Eiffel tower gif]

```
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'PASTE HERE YOUR TOKEN';

    var origin = [2.294514, 48.857475];

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9',
        center: origin,
        zoom: 18,
        pitch: 60,
        bearing: 0
    });

    map.on('style.load', function () {

        map
            .addLayer({
                id: 'custom_layer',
                type: 'custom',
                renderingMode: '3d',
                onAdd: function (map, mbxContext) {

                    window.tb = new Threebox(
                        map,
                        mbxContext,
                        {
                            defaultLights: true,
                        }
                    );

                    // import tower from an external glb file, downscaling it to real size
                    // IMPORTANT: .glb is not a standard MIME TYPE, you'll have to add it to your web server config,
                    // otherwise you'll receive a 404 error
                    var options = {
                        obj: '/3D/eiffel/eiffel.glb',
                        type: 'gltf',
                        scale: 0.01029,
                        units: 'meters',
                        rotation: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, //default rotation
                        adjustment: { x: -0.5, y: -0.5, z: 0 } // place the center in one corner for perfect positioning and rotation
                    }

                    tb.loadObj(options, function (model) {

                        model.setCoords(origin); //position
                        model.setRotation({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 45.7 }); //rotate it

                        tb.add(model);
                    })

                },

                render: function (gl, matrix) {
                    tb.update();
                }
            });
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled across this question and wanted to provide an updated answer for anyone else who ends up here. At the time the question was asked, this was not possible in Mapbox GL JS without a plugin but it can be achieved now with the [CustomLayerInterface](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#customlayerinterface).

Here's an [example of adding a Three.js model to a Mapbox GL JS map](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/).